# Cosmological constant divergence

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, curvature, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

The cosmological constant is measured to be of the order of $10^{120} $ smaller than the value which has been calculated from quantum mechanics. As far as I know, usually this divergence is attributed to some kind of summation error due to unknown effects of the calculation of quantum mechanics on big scales. And the measured cosmological constant is taken as the real one.

1. Only as a thought experiment: What would the universe look like with a much larger (positive) cosmological constant than it has been measured? Would it only expand even faster than today or would we see other effects?
2. Would the negative energy density of the vacuum ($T_{00} \in T$) curve spacetime somehow "statically", in addition to the expansion?
3. Does the actual cosmological constant of our universe (the small one) lead to some kind of "static" curvature? What is talked about regarding the cosmological constant is the *expansion* of the universe (due to vacuum pressure) - but shouldn't there also be some kind of vacuum energy density $T_{00}$ from it and therefore some kind of "static" curvature, in addition to the (accelerated) expansion?

Comment: IIRC, Mandl and Shaw walk through the heuristic derivation of the zero-point energy as cosmological constant in their introductory text on QFT. You may find it profitable to read (or you may find it boring, I dunno, ymmv).

Comment: Welcome to Physics! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

The cosmological constant contributes to our universe's energy density, so it curves spacetime. The answer to #2 and #3 is therefore "yes".

As for #1, if the cosmological constant is negative, then it is attractive, and the universe would quickly collapse into a big crunch. If instead you mean the cosmological constant is positive but much larger than it currently is, then the universe would expand much faster (more technically, the universe becomes dark energy dominated sooner), structure formation would not have time to happen, and there would be no observers in the universe.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I really meant a larger "positive" cosmological constant! I corrected that.

Comment: "The answer to #2 and #3 is yes"- and how would (#2) and can (#3) we observe that? I mean "static" curvature (due to $T_00 from the cosmological constant), in _addition_ to the (accelerated) expansion. Is there/would there be any such (additional) static curvature?